# Страница ищет файлы php не от корня сайта, а от папки, где лежит html файл

Tags: .htaccess, html, php

Весь сайт написан на HTML.

Структура папок такова:
**/www**
  - `.htaccess`
  - `index.html` (в нем выполняется `php/script.php` без ошибок)

**/php**
 - `script.php`

**/files**
 - `index2.html` (в нем не выполняется `php/script.php`, вылазит ошибка, что он ищет файл `php/script.php` из директории `/files/php/script.php`), НО он лежит в корневой папке.

ВОПРОС: как составить `.htaccess`, чтобы `php` выполнялся в `html` из определенной папки, находящейся в корне?

Сейчас `.htaccess` выглядит так:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RemoveHandler .html .htm .php
AddType text/html .htm .html
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена добавлением

```
($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/php/script.php")
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, `php/script.php` замените на

> ../php/script.php

Во-вторых, сделайте все файлы в формате PHP, и все.

А в .htaccess не лезьте.

Comment: Спасибо, но файлы в HTML запускаются от корневой папки правильно, со слешем /php/script.php
Переименовать html в php этот вариант не подойдет для моей задачи(думаю ответ пригодился бы и другим пользователям). Меня интересует запуск из HTML(находящийся в других дерикториях), я пытаюсь понять .htaccess